# Hair particles clumping in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, 3d-view, hair

First time posting :)

I'm relatively new to Blender, and I'm having trouble with hair particles rendering correctly.

This is my viewport render preview, which is the appearance I'm looking for:
[image: viewport]

And this is my render, where the hair clumps unexpectedly:
[image: clumping render]

Can anyone suggest how I might fix this?

Here are my settings:
[image: particle settings]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you upload the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the particle children.
for every 10 hairs displayed in the preview you render 2000 hairs with the same propertys in the final render. Thats why it looks smooth and lumpy.

Comment: Thanks so much :) It seems obvious in hindsight, but that was killing me.